# get var from a previous function in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

As I am new to implementing functions etc beside the basic stuff I am stuck at the moment.
I have a function with a few vars that I want to reuse in another function. Error I get is bigsrc is undefined in the second function. Clearly I am doing something wrong but I cant figure out what it is.

```
$(".villa div a").click(function(){
        var smallsrc = $(this).parent().parent().find(".blueprint a img").attr("src").replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg');    
        var bigsrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        var bigsrc = bigsrc.replace('.jpg', '_big.jpg');
        var villaNaam = $(this).parent().parent().find("h2").text();
        if (bigsrc.indexOf("blueprint") != -1) {
            var smallsrc = $(this).parent().parent().find(".foto a img").attr("src");
        }
        else {
            var smallsrc = $(this).parent().parent().find(".blueprint a img").attr("src");
        }
        var smallsrc = smallsrc.replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg');


         $("#popup-img").fadeIn();
         $("#popup-bg").fadeIn();
         $("#popup-img #titel").append(villaNaam)
         $("#popup-img #big").attr("src", bigsrc);
         $("#popup-img #small").attr("src", smallsrc);
    })
    $("#small-link").click(function(){
            if (bigsrc.indexOf("blueprint") != -1) {
                var smallsrc = smallsrc.replace('blueprint', 'huis');
                var bigsrc = smallsrc.replace('huis', 'blueprint');
            }
            else {
                var smallsrc = smallsrc.replace('huis', 'blueprint');
                var bigsrc = smallsrc.replace('blueprint', 'huis');
            }
     });
```

Comment: Move the variable to an outer scope where both functions can see it...?

Answer (score 0):

Try global variables.

```
var myVariable=2;
function myFunc(){
    console.log(myVariable)
}
myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with [Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))

You are creating your variables inside of the $(".villa div a").click function.

To be able to use them elsewhere, create the variables at a higher level (outside of that function), and then assign to them inside your function.

```
 var bigsrc = $(document).find("img").attr("src");
 var smallsrc = $(document).find(".foto a img").attr("src");
$(".villa div a").click(function(){
        var smallsrc = $(this).parent().parent().find(".blueprint a img").attr("src").replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg');    
        bigsrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        bigsrc = bigsrc.replace('.jpg', '_big.jpg');
        var villaNaam = $(this).parent().parent().find("h2").text();
        if (bigsrc.indexOf("blueprint") != -1) {
            smallsrc = $(this).parent().parent().find(".foto a img").attr("src");
        }
        else {
            smallsrc = $(this).parent().parent().find(".blueprint a img").attr("src");
        }
        smallsrc = smallsrc.replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg');


         $("#popup-img").fadeIn();
         $("#popup-bg").fadeIn();
         $("#popup-img #titel").append(villaNaam)
         $("#popup-img #big").attr("src", bigsrc);
         $("#popup-img #small").attr("src", smallsrc);
    })
    $("#small-link").click(function(){
            if (bigsrc.indexOf("blueprint") != -1) {
                smallsrc = smallsrc.replace('blueprint', 'huis');
                bigsrc = smallsrc.replace('huis', 'blueprint');
            }
            else {
                smallsrc = smallsrc.replace('huis', 'blueprint');
                bigsrc = smallsrc.replace('blueprint', 'huis');
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".villa div a").click(function(){
    // ..
    bigsrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    bigsrc = bigsrc.replace('.jpg', '_big.jpg');
    $("#small-link").data("bigsrc", bigsrc);
    // ..
});

$("#small-link").click(function(){
        if ($(this).data("bigsrc").indexOf("blueprint") != -1) // ..
// ..
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/x0jnav0t/